# CSS defining extra whitespace after last element

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a small project for myself to try and experiment with HTML5 and CSS3, to get the hang of it. I need help solving a weird - in my eyes - and unexpected CSS quirk.

I have put my work on CodePen.io to see: http://codepen.io/jbehrens94/pen/uKgvH

The thing is, I want all `<section>`'s to be 100% in height, so every section fills the exact 100% width and height of the browser's screen. The thing is, if you scroll down to the bottom, there is a lot of white and I can't find out why.

I have noticed margins not working well, so I worked around them, mostly by using paddings. 
I tried changing display's, floats and so on, but I just can not seem to find what the problem is and why there is a lot of white on the bottom.

It should not be there, as there are no elements after the last section.

Comment: Generally speaking, the best approach to figuring out what's going on is to simplify the html and css to the most basic it can be.  Then start layering new things until it breaks.  Then look at the last thing you added to see what's going on.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your `html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}`. I could be wrong, but setting `height` to `95%` definitely helped.

Comment: ChrisLively: That is actually what I did, I divided the page into sections, it worked at that moment, so after the basics, something went wrong, but I am not sure what is.

Anyhow, thank you for the edit and for replying!

Agony: I will try and see if there is something wrong with my relative/fluid layout, thank you for thinking together with me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three `<div />`s with classes `file`, `sites`, and `contact` on your last page which start about halfway down but have a CSS declaration forcing them to be 100% height.

Comment: Oh yes, you are a hero! I guess I have been neglecting to check the code I reused, thanks a lot for helping me out!
You solved the problem and I gave you an +1 :)

Comment: @JohannBehrens Browser developer tools can save you a lot of headache. I got this answer just by right-clicking the space you didn't want and choosing "Inspect this element in Firebug."

Comment: I guess I should use them more often, thanks for making me realize, haha!